# GetTickCount64 error using Python and C++

Tags: c++, python-2.7, windows-xp, gettickcount

I'm attempting to embed a python module within a larger c++ program (Relevant details:VS2005, WinXP Python 2.7). When I create a new instance of the class that includes 'python.h' and attempt to run my program I get the error message "The procedure entry point GetTickCount64 could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.ll".
I've read online that this happens because GetTickCount64 doesn't exist in XP so I made sure to add the correct windows headers to all of my files. However I still get the error and it occurs even if I comment out everything in the offending class except the include for Python.h. 
So to get to an actual question. I was wondering if Python itself could be calling or including GetTickCount64 and if so how to stop it from doing so.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Guess I posted to fast since I think I've got it sorted myself. For anyone else in the same position I downloaded the Python source and compiled with Windows XP flags in VS2005 and all seems well with the world.